# Submit AJAX Post onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to figure out why this isn't working, I don't want to have a submit button to click, It does work if I have one though, instead I use `onchange="this.form.submit()"` and that posts the form as it normally would, not AJAX background style, I didn't code the ajax part, I found it and made it work for my situation, but as far as I know `$('#ajaxform').submit(function ()`, submit is submit? Why isn't `onchange="this.form.submit()"` and `<input type="submit" />` the same type of submit? What am I missing?

```
    <form method="post" action="~/getAJAX.cshtml" id="ajaxform" name="form">
        @* -------- Div to hold form elements -------- *@
        <div class="reportDateDiv">

            @* -------- Text --------- *@
            <a class="blackColor fSize18 RPtxt">Reporting Period</a>

            @* -------- Start day box -------- *@
            <input type="text" name="inputDate" spellcheck="false" class="datepickerS metricDateTextbox capitalFirst"
                  onchange="this.form.submit()" value="@inputDate" autocomplete="off" placeholder="@placeholderStartDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy")" readonly="readonly" />

            @* -------- Text --------- *@
            <a class="blackColor fSize16 RPtxt RPtxtTo">to</a>

            @* -------- End day box --------- *@
            <input type="text" name="endDate" spellcheck="false" class="datepickerE metricDateTextbox capitalFirst"
                  onchange="this.form.submit()" value="@endDate" autocomplete="off" placeholder="@noEndDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy")" readonly="readonly" />

        </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#ajaxform').submit(function () { // catch the form's submit event
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
                url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
                success: function (response) { // on success..
                    $('#here').html(response); // update the DIV
                }
            });
            return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you edit your explanatory text so we can make sense of it? What do you want? And what are you getting instead?

Comment: If I remove `onchange="this.form.submit()"` from my input textboxes and put a submit button in my form instead, everything works as it should, it gets what I want in the background and shows it like AJAX would, however, with the onchange submit thing, it doesnt do the AJAX part, it just posts the form as if there was no AJAX, it reloads the page. @ChrisG

Comment: I can confirm this; apparently calling `submit()` on the form skips the `onsubmit` handler. The solution is to wrap your ajax call in a function and put a call to it in the `onchange` handlers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Comment: Would you perhaps know how to do that? If so, please put it as an answer! @ChrisG

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this in your form:

```
<input ... onchange="mySubmit(this.form)" ... >
```

Change the script to this:

```
function mySubmit(theForm) {
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $(theForm).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(theForm).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(theForm).attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function (response) { // on success..
            $('#here').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Absolutely awesome! Thanks for your help!

Comment: You made my day! Thank you!

Comment: Brilliant ! jQuery, JS and all that have changed and it's hard to keep up, so thank you for your time and sollution !

Comment: I searched for hours for a solution and this is it!! Thanks so much for the answer!