# First input data decides the next field's data in form

Tags: jquery, mysql, forms, insert

Not here to ask for help with my code but I'm wondering if is it possible that in a form when I type in a 'name' in the first input, the next field in the form for 'passport number' to be filled automatically from the database without submitting the form. I'm clear that jquery needed to perform such a task but can you give me the right term/name to search on the internet? I come across the conditional dropdown but I want it to fill it by itself.

```
 <label>Employee name</label>
        <input type="text" name="emp_name" class="form-control" placeholder="" required>
    </div>

 <label>Passport Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="pass_no" class="form-control" placeholder="" required>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to use ajax for that. When input is filled active ajax and fill the input. I suggest you to use select box instead of normal input

Comment: Maybe this post will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355298/submit-ajax-post-onchange/42355528